# Calculating the barycentric coordinates for a point in a triangle?

Tags: geometry, barycentric-coordinates

How would I find the corresponding $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ for the point $p$ with respect to the triangle with vertices $a$, $b$, and $c$?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_barycentric_and_Cartesian_coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple method presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" and "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", namely calculate
$$
\vec{\Lambda} = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \vec{e}_1 & \vec{e}_2 & \vec{e}_3 \\
            p_x & a_x & b_x & c_x \\
            p_y & a_y & b_y & c_y \\
            1   &  1  & 1   & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a_x & b_x & c_x \\
        a_y & b_y & c_y \\
         1  & 1   & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
} = \alpha \vec{e}_1 + \beta \vec{e}_2 + \gamma \vec{e}_3
$$
Here $\vec{e}_1$, $\vec{e}_2$, and $\vec{e}_3$ are some formal orthonormal vectors. Components of "vector" $\vec{\Lambda}$ will be equal to barycentric coordinates.

**EXAMPLE**

Let $a = (-2;-1)$, $b = (3; -1)$, and $c = (1;4)$. I want to calculate barycentric coordinates of $p = (2;1)$. The equation above gives
$$
\vec{\Lambda} = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \vec{e}_1 & \vec{e}_2 & \vec{e}_3 \\
            2 & -2 & 3  & 1 \\
            1 & -1 & -1 & 4 \\
            1 &  1 & 1  & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 3  & 1 \\
        -1 & -1 & 4 \\
         1 & 1  & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
} = \frac{1}{25} \vec{e}_1 + \frac{14}{25} \vec{e}_2 + \frac{2}{5}\vec{e}_3,
$$
thus barycentric coordinates of $p$ are $\alpha=1/25$, $\beta=14/25$, and $\gamma=2/5$.

**MULTIPLE DIMENSIONS**

The general formula for any dimension is
$$
\vec{\Lambda} =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \vec{e}_{1} & \vec{e}_{2} & \dots & \vec{e}_{n+1} \\
        \begin{matrix}
            x_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            x_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            x_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            x_{1}^{(1)}  \\
            x_{2}^{(1)}  \\
            \cdots       \\
            x_{n}^{(1)}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            x_{1}^{(2)}  \\
            x_{2}^{(2)}  \\
            \cdots       \\
            x_{n}^{(2)}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \cdots &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            \!x_{1}^{(n+1)}\! \\
            \!x_{2}^{(n+1)}\! \\
            \cdots        \\
            \!x_{n}^{(n+1)}\! \\
        \end{matrix} \\
%
        1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}
            x_{1}^{(1)} \\
            x_{2}^{(1)} \\
            \cdots      \\
            x_{n}^{(1)} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            x_{1}^{(2)} \\
            x_{2}^{(2)} \\
            \cdots      \\
            x_{n}^{(2)} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \cdots &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            \! x_{1}^{(n+1)}\! \\
            \!x_{2}^{(n+1)}\! \\
            \!\cdots \!       \\
           \! x_{n}^{(n+1)} \!\\
        \end{matrix} \\
%
        1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
}.
$$
Here $\vec{x}^{\,(1)}$, $\dots$, $\vec{x}^{\,(n+1)}$ are vertices of the simplex,
$x_{1}$, $\dots$, $x_{n}$ --- coordinates of the point, which barycentric coordinates you want to know, and $\vec{e}_{1}$, $\dots$, $\vec{e}_{n+1}$ are some formal orthonormal vectors.
As a result you get a "vector" $\vec{\Lambda}$, which components are barycentric coordinates of the point $\vec{x}$.

**REFERENCES**

To read more on the theory everything relies on, you may want to check "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" that is written by authors of the formula, or check concrete example in their "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)".

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1.$$
You also have 
$$\alpha a + \beta b + \gamma c = p.$$
Harvest three equations in three unknowns by unpacking the coordinates in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

> **Lemma about areas**
>   If triangles APQ and BPQ have common side PQ,  then the ratio in which the line PQ divides AB  is up to a sign equal to $S_{APQ}:S_{BPQ}$

So, $[S_{PBC} : S_{PAC} : S_{PAB}]$ are (not normalized) barycentric coordinates of $P$ with respect to $ABC$.

In your problem, $[S_{PBC} : S_{PAC} : S_{PAB}] = [1 : S_{PAC}: \frac{3}{2}] = [1 : 3- 1 -\frac{3}{2}: \frac{3}{2}] = [2: 1 : 3] $